# Looping through Arrays in Dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary, multidimensional-array

Typical noob disclaimer goes here ;) I am trying to nest an array in a Swift dictionary similar to how you would with JSON. My nested array ("blocks" in the code below) has mixed datatypes in it. When I run my For-in loop on it, I get the error **For-in loop requires 'Any' to conform to 'Sequence'** which sounds like it's helpful - but I'm not sure what to do here. Would love some advice.

My dict:

```
let levelOneData = [
    "goal": 180,
    "gravity": CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -4.0),
    "bombs": 12,
    "blocks": [
        0: [
            "blockSize": "Small",
            "blockPosition": [0, 80],
            "blockIsLocked": false
        ] as [String : Any],
        1: [
            "blockSize": "Medium",
            "blockPosition": [0, 0],
            "blockIsLocked": false
        ] as [String : Any],
    ]
] as [String : Any]
```

My For loop:

```
for (index, block) in levelOneData["blocks"]! { <<<< error here
    print(block) 
}
```

Comment: The value of the `"blocks"` key is not an array. It's another dictionary. It just happens to have keys of type `Int` instead of `String`.

Comment: Why not use proper `structs` for your data?

Comment: Hey @HangarRash I did try structs also - I need a nested array that I can loop through and couldn't find a way to do that with structs. I'm coming from web/JSON and feel like this is a simple thing to do but am missing something important.

Comment: The important thing you are missing is that by using `Any` you will need to cast the values every time you read from your type and this will lead to code that is much harder to read and understand and also more error prone. And generally be more fragile if you need to refactor it. If you use custom types instead then the compiler will tell you directly that you made a mistake instead of the code misbehaving or even crashing when you run it.

Comment: Hmmm ok @JoakimDanielson thanks. Does that mean I should type each line of the duct separately?

Comment: See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you start using custom types instead using `struct`, `enum` and/or `class` instead if a nested dictionary with `Any` types.

This will mean you can avoid casting your values all the time and you get shorter, clearer and less error prone code since the compiler will detect type errors and more.

Here is an example on how to do it

```
struct LevelData {
    var goal: Int
    var gravity: CGVector
    var bombs: Int
    var blocks: [Block]
}

struct Block {
    var size: String
    var position: [Int]
    var isLocked: Bool
}
```

Then create an object using the generated member wise inits

```
let levelOne = LevelData(goal: 180, gravity: CGVector.init(dx: 0.0, dy: -4.0), bombs: 12, blocks: [
    Block(size: "Small", position: [0,80], isLocked: false),
    Block(size: "Medium", position: [0,0], isLocked: false)
])
```

To loop over the inner array now becomes much simpler

```
for block in levelOne.blocks {
    print(block.size)
    //...
}
```

Another improvement could be to replace the size strings with an enum

```
enum BlockSize {
    case small
    case medium
    case large
}
```

And then change the `Block` type and how you create it

```
struct Block {
    var size: BlockSize
    var position: [Int]
    var isLocked: Bool
}

Block(size: .small, position: [0,80], isLocked: false)
```

Comment: A further improvement could be to replace the array for `position` with a custom type as well

Comment: This is fantastic - I really appreciate your time on it. I will for sure refactor this. Looks super clean and simple. Thank you! I guess my initial question could have been around using the correct data format vs. looping in a dict ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because the semicyclic form of levelOneData["blocks"]! is Any type, you must explicitly declare the type for use in a repeating statement such as for-in.

Referring to the content of levelOneData at the top, it seems appropriate to use [Int: [String: Any]] as the type casting.
Please refer to the example code below.

```
    func printData() {
        if let data = levelOneData["blocks"] as? [Int: [String: Any]] {
            for (index, block) in data {
                print(block)
            }
        }
    }
```

or

```
    func printData() {
        guard let data = levelOneData["blocks"] as? [Int: [String: Any]] else {
            return
        }
        
        for (index, block) in data {
            print(block)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This was the right answer to my problem. However, the patterns aren't the greatest and required a lot of typecasting. I refactored using the struct solution from Joakim above and the data was much easier to use. Thank you, everyone! I learned a lot.